# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 8000401a

Tags: com, ms-word, components, clsid

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 8000401a.

We are getting above said error from our production server which is hosted in SharePoint farm environment, where as not able to reproduce the same issue from our staging server which is standalone server.

I hope, the above said error will be throwing when Microsoft.Office.Word component accessing from remote machine. I've updated all users under "Launch and activation Permission" in DCOMConfig as mentioned in [Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID Error: 8000401a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139834/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-with-clsid-error-8000401a)

The interesting here is, the issue has been resolved automatically when user keeps clicking on the "Report Generation" button in my web page. I understand the issue seems to be happened on occasionally as we cannot predicate when this will be thrown.

Comment: "The server process could not be started".  Running Word on a server is a bad idea.  It doesn't take many users to make the server keel over, Word is a very expensive process.  It was designed to be a desktop app.  One user, one instance of Word.

Comment: It's also not officially supported ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757 ): Word is built as an interactive application, and at my company we already got a blocked server because of an unplanned message box (which turned out to be "too many spelling errors" due to a language conflict). Word does not have a "silent" mode.

Comment: @HansPassant how does that answer his question?  Sharepoint is a waste of time too but that's not fixing his issue.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution,

using DCOMCNFG.exe open it and go to Component Service ->Computers->My Computer->DCOM Config-> check for Microsoft Office Word option and select tab Security.Here you will get the options for Launch and Activation Permission->select Customize and click on edit and the add the user that will runs your Application with full access.

That's all ,this resolve my problem hop this will help.

Answer (score 1):

This [appears](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21370816) to be a permissions error.  you may need to look through your code and configuration to ensure that all passwords are correct and everyone has the right permissions.